# Is there a way to run code when an assembly loads?

Tags: reflection, .net-4.0, appdomain

I'm building an application that will load untrusted assemblies for inspection (i.e. retrieval of the assembly full name).  For security reasons, I'm trying to think of a way that these assemblies could be written that would allow them to execute code when loaded.  I haven't code up with a method yet, but wanted to throw it out here to see if anyone could.

I'm aware that I could load these assemblies into an untrusted app domain, effectively stopping them from doing almost anything, but I wanted to avoid the complexity if it's un-needed.

Specifically, I will be calling `Assembly.Load` and `<LoadedAssebmly>.FullName`.  Maybe there's a better way to load the assembly name without using the `Assembly` class?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's the `AssemblyName` class. It allows you to find the assembly's name without loading it. Second, you can load assemblies using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad`, which uses the reflection-only context -- no code can be executed from such an assembly.

Comment: Perfect!  This is what I need to do.  I assume that this is not prone to the module initializers mentioned in Daniel's post?

Comment: It shouldn't be, but I suggest that you make sure if this is important to you from a security perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible: [.Net: Running code when assembly is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505237/net-running-code-when-assembly-is-loaded)

I suggest, you use a method to inspect the assembly, that doesn't load it, i.e. [`Mono.Cecil`](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)