# Run code when Assembly is loaded

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, clr-module-initializer

I have some code in my library that I want to run on the fly when the assemnly is loaded. Similar to how for example Owin auto inilitize itself.

Is this the way you do it?
[.Net: Running code when assembly is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505237/net-running-code-when-assembly-is-loaded)

Comment: Yes, it is. Unless you want to use the static initializers of your classes.

Comment: Ok, I guess Fody is the way todo it then