# Call a c# method once on load of a class library

Tags: c#, methods

I have a Logging project (class library) that is referenced by other projects.

When the Logging library is first loaded, I want it to run a method to confirm that directories exist, and if not, create them.

I have tried creating a Main method in the Logging project, but this doesn't trigger.

Comment: You don't load projects, you load assemblies. I assume you are talking about a class library?

Comment: yes @KlausGütter class library

Comment: Then there is no `Main`. Could you add the code to a constructor of some "central object" in your library? It all depends on how the API of the library is structured.

Comment: A static constructor should do. Assuming you have single class in assembly or all classes are dependent on the one with constructor, or all classes have static constructors. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/505237/1997232)

Answer (score -1):

The answer was to add a static constructor.

```
public static class Hello
{
    static Hello() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, @DanPettis there is a subtlety; a static constructor is not invoked when it's containing assembly is loaded - it's invoked the first time code needing the type it is jitted, which may or may not be a problem depending on your scenario.

Comment: Also, you might have a hard time finding errors if the code in the type initializer throws an exception (which is not unlikely if you are dealing with I/O).